# gameDisplay.fill(White) NameError: name 'gameDisplay' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i got this error

> gameDisplay.fill(White) NameError: name 'gameDisplay' is not defined

my code

```
    import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

width=800
height=600
TITLE="test"
FrameRate=30

#images
ball=pygame.image.load("Red_Ball.png")

#Color
Black=(0,0,0)
White=(255,255,255)
#fonctions
def Ball(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(ball,(x,y))


GameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()



x=width*0.45
y=height*0.8


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==quit :
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    gameDisplay.fill(White)
    Ball(x,y)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FrameRate)
```

What's the problem here?i got python 3 and I'm trying to fill the background to white.

Comment: you have `GameDisplay` with upper `G`, change it to lower `g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable deceleration is off.

You declare it as

`GameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))`

However you're calling it with

`gameDisplay.fill(White)`

Change it to `GameDisplay.fill(White)` and you'll be set.